# Asynchronously call faceapi.detectAllFaces()

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I am using [face-api.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/) to detect faces in a given image. Everything is configured as mentioned on Github and detection is working.

But I want to call `faceapi.detectAllFaces()` asynchronously, I means I don't want to wait for its result, so I can't call `await faceapi.detectAllFaces()`. I tried below code:

In cam.js

```
async function detectFace()
{
    document.getElementById('camPic').src = getCurrentImageAsBase64(); //getCurrentImageAsBase64() gets the image in base64 format from canvas
    return faceapi.detectAllFaces(document.getElementById('camPic'), new faceapi.SsdMobilenetv1Options());  
}
```

In index.jsp

```
$('#camPrcd').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); 
    detectFace().then((arr) => console.log(arr));
    console.log('detection called');
});
```

After button click, on console I can see message "detection called" and after sometime detection result gets logged from `then()` block.

But my observation is when `detectFace()` is called the html page feels like hanged (not able to click on any button) and when `arr` gets printed on console then I can able to click on page.

Looks like even though "detection called" message gets printed immediately before detection happens but `faceapi.detectAllFaces()` is not doing work asynchronously.

*Note: This happens only for first call of `faceapi.detectAllFaces()` as per author of face-api.js during first call model for face detection get compiled and so detection time is more at first call as compare to subsequent call to function.*

So is there any way that, I can call for detection and still web page is accessible and when it's finished a callback function will handle the detection result.